# Expansion of elementary symmetric function in Jack's?

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

Consider the expansion

$$
e_\mu(x) = \sum_\lambda c_{\mu\lambda}(\alpha) J_\lambda^{(\alpha)}(x)
$$
where $J_\lambda^{(\alpha)}(x)$ are the integral-form Jack polynomials (the ones with $n!$ as coefficient of $m_{1^n}(x)$).

Is there some result which proves that each $c_{\mu\lambda}(\alpha)$ is of the form $P(\alpha)/Q(\alpha)$, where $P,Q \in \mathbb{N}[\alpha]$?

It seems that $Q$ can be chosen as some $Q_\mu(\alpha)$ that factors in a nice way (some product of deformed hook values perhaps?)

Comment: What about the choice of $\alpha$?

Comment: Well, there's no choice, it is an indeterminate. So coefficients depend on $\alpha$. For $\alpha=1$, you get (a multiple of) the classical Kostka coefficients, and for $\alpha=\infy$, one get the monomial expansion of the $e$'s (again, up to non-negative constants).

Comment: An affirmative answer to the first question would follow from the known conjecture that $\langle J_\lambda,J_\mu J_\nu\rangle\in\mathbb{N}[\alpha]$ since $e_n=J_{1^n}$ and $\langle J_\lambda,J_\lambda\rangle\in \mathbb{N}[\alpha]$. (In fact,  $\langle J_\lambda,J_\lambda\rangle$ has a simple explicit factorization into linear factors.) The scalar product is the the Jack scalar product (so the $J_\lambda$'s are orthogonal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding my comment above, note that by induction we only need to show that $\langle J_\lambda, J_{1^n}J_\nu\rangle\in\mathbb{N}[\alpha]$. This follows from the dual Pieri formula for Jack polynomials (obtained by combining Theorems 3.3 and 6.1 of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/73.pdf), so we do get $c_{\mu\lambda}(\alpha)\in\mathbb{N}[\alpha]$, as well as a factorization of $Q_\mu(\alpha)$ into linear factors.

Answer (score 1):

I was told the following argument, due to V. Feray.

First, note that $J^{(\alpha)}_\lambda$ expands in the monomial basis with rational coefficients, where both numerator and denominator have rational coefficients (this is due to the Knop-Sahi formula).

Now, since the homogeneous symmetric functions are dual to the monomial symmetric functions, and since the Jacks are self-dual, we should have that the complete homogeneous symmetric functions expands positively in the Jack basis.

Finally, one needs to apply the $\omega$ involution on both sides, and basically have the positivity (one needs to do some work to verify that $\omega$ on Jack polynomials behaves well).